# upload and save file through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I new to this site as well as to ajax, before posting here, although I searched for, nut not get proper answer to my question.

I have form through which I can upload and than save file, all this happening through ajax.

```
    $('#'+loader).fadeIn('fast');

    var input = document.getElementById(fileid);
    file = input.files[0];

    var filename= $('#'+fileid).val();
    var exts = ["pdf", "doc", "docx", "PDF", "DOC", "DOCX"];
    if(file != undefined){
    formData= new FormData();

    if ( filename ) 
    {
        // split file name at dot
        var get_ext = filename.split('.');
        // reverse name to check extension
        get_ext = get_ext.reverse();
        // check file type is valid as given in 'exts' array
        if ( $.inArray ( get_ext[0].toLowerCase(), exts ) > -1 ){ var found = true; } else { var found = false; }
    }


    if(found) {
        formData.append("image", file);
        $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.length!=0)
            {
                $('#'+loader).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+errorid).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+exerror).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+hide1).fadeOut('fast');
                $('#'+successid).fadeIn('fast');
                $('#'+inputhidden).val(data);
                $('#'+imgname).fadeIn('fast');
                $('#'+filesavebtn).fadeIn('fast');
                $('#'+imgname).html(data);
            }else if(data.length==0)
            {
                $('#'+loader).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+exerror).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+successid).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+hide1).fadeOut('fast');
                $('#'+errorid).fadeIn('fast');
            }       
        }
        });
    }
    else{
      $('#'+loader).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+errorid).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+successid).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+hide1).fadeOut('fast');
      $('#'+exerror).fadeIn('fast');
    } 

  }else{

  }
```

and getting saved through

```
var fileval= $('#'+fileid).val();
var fileuniqval= $('#'+fileuniqid).val();

$.ajax({
    url: pageurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'fileupload='+fileval+'&identi='+fileuniqval+'&uniqids=fileuploading',
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data=='FALSE'){ 
            alert("Server Error, please try again.");
        }if(data=='TRUE'){
            $('#'+hide1).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+hide2).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+hide3).fadeOut('fast');
            $('#'+inputid).val('');
            $('#'+successmsg).fadeIn('fast');
            $('#'+filearea).css({ 'border-color': '#008000', 'border-width':'2px', 'border-style':'solid' });
            $('#'+filearea).animate({ 'backgroundColor': '#008000', 'color': '#fff'}, 1000);
            $('#'+filearea).animate({ 'backgroundColor': '#fff', 'color': '#000'}, 3000);
        }
    }
});
```

Now my question is that I want to get this upload and save procedure in one go! Although I tried my to merge both function by nesting one in other but not working as per expectations.

```
$('#'+loader).fadeIn('fast');

    var input = document.getElementById(fileid);
    file = input.files[0];

    var filename= $('#'+fileid).val();
    var exts = ["pdf", "doc", "docx", "PDF", "DOC", "DOCX"];

    var fileval= $('#'+inputhidden).val();
    var fileuniqval= $('#'+fileuniqid).val();

    if(file != undefined){
    formData= new FormData();

    if ( filename ) 
    {
        // split file name at dot
        var get_ext = filename.split('.');
        // reverse name to check extension
        get_ext = get_ext.reverse();
        // check file type is valid as given in 'exts' array
        if ( $.inArray ( get_ext[0].toLowerCase(), exts ) > -1 ){ var found = true; } else { var found = false; }
    }


    if(found) {
        formData.append("image", file);
        $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.length!=0)
            {
                $('#'+loader).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+errorid).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+exerror).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+hide1).fadeOut('fast');
                $('#'+successid).fadeIn('fast');
                $('#'+inputhidden).val(data);
                $('#'+imgname).fadeIn('fast');
                //$('#'+filesavebtn).fadeIn('fast');
                $('#'+imgname).html(data);

                $.ajax({
                    url: pageurl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'fileupload='+fileval+'&identi='+fileuniqval+'&uniqids=fileuploading',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        if(data=='FALSE'){ 
                            alert("Server Error, please try again.");
                        }if(data=='TRUE'){
                            $('#'+successid).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+exerror).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+errorid).fadeOut('fast');
                            $('#'+fileid).val('');
                            $('#'+hide1).fadeIn('fast');
                            $('#'+filearea).css({ 'border-color': '#008000', 'border-width':'2px', 'border-style':'solid' });
                            $('#'+filearea).animate({ 'backgroundColor': '#008000', 'color': '#fff'}, 1000);
                            $('#'+filearea).animate({ 'backgroundColor': '#fff', 'color': '#000'}, 3000);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else if(data.length==0)
            {
                $('#'+loader).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+exerror).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+successid).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+hide1).fadeOut('fast');
                $('#'+errorid).fadeIn('fast');
            }       
        }
        });
    }
    else{
      $('#'+loader).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+errorid).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+successid).fadeOut('fast');$('#'+hide1).fadeOut('fast');
      $('#'+exerror).fadeIn('fast');
    } 

  }else{

  }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting there, man

Comment: what you want us to help with if you dont tell the exact problem.

Comment: I want upload and save that file into database through ajax. Previously It is happening through two different functions.

Comment: what is the error now you get in browser or where does it fail?

Comment: file uploading but not getting saved, It want when file uploading finishes, it should get saved itself.

Comment: http://www.codingcage.com/2014/12/file-upload-and-view-with-php-and-mysql.html     check this page it will help you better

Comment: Thanks trying... for your reply, but I want to get it done through ajax.

Comment: Yes, the site does the form submitting and retrieving through ajax, give a try